# Does Rubymine support "let" syntax in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, intellij-idea, capybara, rubymine

I am using Rubymine to create a project in Rails4, rspec and capybara. When I use the `let` syntax for defining variables in Capybara features, it seems RubyMine isn't able to detect the existence of the variables. For instance in this code below, the variable `capsuleHash`, `capsuleForm` and `capsuleViewPage` are all not being recognized in intelliJ in the scenario section. Does anyone have a workaround?

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  feature 'Capsules Feature' do

   let(:capsuleHash) {attributes_for(:tdd_capsule)}
   let(:capsuleForm) {CapsuleCreateForm.new}
   let(:capsuleViewPage) {CapsuleViewPage.new}

   scenario 'Add a new capsule and displays the capsule in view mode' do

   visit '/capsules/new'

   expect{
    capsuleForm.submit_form(capsuleHash)
   }.to change(Capsule,:count).by(1)

   capsuleViewPage.validate_on_page
   expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:title]
   expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:description]
   expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:study_text]
   expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:assignment_instructions]
   expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:guidelines_for_evaluators]
   expect(page).to have_link 'Edit'

  end

end
```

Comment: Can you share the specific error you're getting and any related stacktrace?

Comment: There is no stack trace Peter. It works fine when I run the feature in rspec. The problem is that since RubyMine doesn't detect the existence of these variables, I don't get auto-complete feature with dots, and it puts a squiggly line underneath, which I find annoying.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and it is very annoying. Have you found a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RubyMine other than it's an IDE for Ruby. The way you phrased your question, though, I'm assuming that you're referring to some feature of RubyMine which displays the "variables" defined at any particular point in a program.

If this is case, the reason that the symbols you've passed to `let` wouldn't "show up" as variables is because they are not being *defined* as variables.  They are being defined as *methods* which return the value of the associated block. On the first call from within each `it` block, the value of the block is remembered and that value returned on subsequent calls within the same block.

Note that there is nothing wrong with the RSpec code in terms of defining those methods. The following code passes, for example:

```
class Page
  def has_content?(content) true ; end
  def has_link?(link) true ; end
end

page = Page.new

class CapsuleCreateForm
  def submit_form(hash)
    Capsule.increment_count
  end
end

class CapsuleViewPage
  def validate_on_page
  end
end

def attributes_for(symbol)
  {}
end

def visit(path)
end

class Capsule
  @@count = 0

  def self.count
    @@count
  end

  def self.increment_count
    @@count += 1
  end

end

describe 'Capsules Feature' do

  let(:capsuleHash) {attributes_for(:tdd_capsule)}
  let(:capsuleForm) {CapsuleCreateForm.new}
  let(:capsuleViewPage) {CapsuleViewPage.new}

  it 'Add a new capsule and displays the capsule in view mode' do

    visit '/capsules/new'

    puts method(:capsuleHash)

    expect{
    capsuleForm.submit_form(capsuleHash)
    }.to change(Capsule,:count).by(1)

    capsuleViewPage.validate_on_page
    expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:title]
    expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:description]
    expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:study_text]
    expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:assignment_instructions]
    expect(page).to have_content capsuleHash[:guidelines_for_evaluators]
    expect(page).to have_link 'Edit'

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

RubyMine does support `let` blocks, but you'll need to be sure to use the latest version, 6.0.2. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14673

Comment: I did upgrade my RubyMine on your suggestion from 6.0.1 to 6.0.2, but the error 'Unresolved Ruby Reference' still shows up for those variables defined in let. Your link does seem to indicate that its been fixed in 6.0.2, but for me its still the same. I am running on a Mac, and I did invalidate the RubyMine Cache to confirm. Any tips?